# Why would the relationship between period and mass be important to you in a Simple Harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

My lab's teacher always asks us why we're there at lab before the class starts. We already know the variables we're supposed to measure, so we frequently say (We used to say): "We want to find out the relationship between period and mass. Of course, as you might expect the teacher doesn't accept that answer. He replies: "Well, you do want to know that, but why is it important for you to know that? I understand curiosity could play an important role, but be honest, do you care about the relationship of these two variables just like that?" He wants us to convey our motivation to conduct the experiment, otherwise you can not start the class.

I do think this is getting the best out of me; however I've been thinking about it for like two weeks, and I must start my lab report, and I can not do it without a research problem. At class, my first proposal was (I hope it wasn't too bad): We are planning to open a slingshot ride, and we want as many people as possible to board the game; therefore, we want each game to last the shortest possible time . In that way we're so interested in correlating mass with period since we have conjectured a more massive body should be harder to be sped up by the elastic force of the game strings and to be slowed down; as a result; it would take more time for the game to complete a cycle. Therefore, we would put less weight to be lifted by the strings, so more people can aboard the game.

However, my experiment was only about a mass and spring system oscillating, so my teacher told me the experiment could hardly solve my problem , and now I do understand him since there were two strings on the game (more complex system perhaps) the air resistance is great in that game, whereas my experiment was totally different; thus, I couldn't generalize my results. So now I'm looking for more similar to my experiment. I was wondering about bungee( I don't know it could be a simple harmonic motion approximation) Or a pogo stick, thing which looks attractive to me, but I have no idea why I would correlate mass with period. I'm kind of lost. I hope I haven't overwhelmed you. I just want some advice to keep improving at lab classes. Maybe, you could help me with some other applications that I haven't observed.

Comment: Hmmm... I am not going to mince my words here: if that is really the assignment (I doubt a little that it is), then your teacher needs to get a new job. The motivation for scientific experiments is to learn about nature. Period. Full stop. End of story. Scientists aren't making up new reasons for why they want to do a new experiment. They have ONE reason and ONE reason only. Applications are absolutely secondary and are simply a consequence of what can be learned in science. OTOH, it's perfectly possible that your teacher wants to hear just that... so tell him!

Comment: @CuriousOne: I agree but I don't think it's per se wrong to think of possible applications, i.e. reasons why one would conduct certain experiments other than learn about nature. Perhaps the asker should think about 'real world' applications of spring-mass systems?

Comment: @Gert: If you want to teach science to kids, then you should be teaching them science. I have absolutely nothing against teaching them engineering in addition, but that's not what this lab class is about, is it? If it were about engineering, then the kids would have to consider the cost of the design, the production/construction schedule, calculate the reliability and include the necessary safety based on the local engineering codes. I don't think that's what this lab is teaching, is it?

Comment: @CuriousOne: in a certain large country (cough!) this utilitarian approach is quite popular. I'm not a fan myself but I think that education system sees that approach as motivational, a way to seduce people to science.

Comment: Well, not necessarily and application. Perhaps what he meant was an observation around us that makes us wonder about this relationship.

Comment: @Gert: You are right (cough!). As you can see in the example above, the approach produces kids who can't tell what the fundamental driving force for science is (curiosity-cough-cough...). I am sure the same kid can't tell the difference between science and engineering or even between science and pseudoscience. How could he? He isn't being told the most simple of facts about it, rather he is being sent to fetch the intellectual equivalent of a "Siemens Lufthaken" (loosely translated a "GE skyhook").

Comment: @Omar: That's just as questionable to deny your entry into a lab. The only relevant questions here are along the lines of "Which variables exist in an experiment?". Your personal observations/curiosity have nothing to do with those variables. There are systematic ways to establish what is and is not relevant in an experiment and that is worthwhile learning, but for that you have to take yourself out of the equation completely and you have to focus on the experiment. Is your teacher teaching you that?

Comment: @CuriousOne: you're looking at this very rigidly. And one kid doesn't make spring.

Comment: @Gert: One bad teacher makes hundreds of poorly educated kids.